# how to use grid material ui?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, grid

I have a component whose grid looks like this:
**component Region:**

```
<Grid container spacing={10} >
        <Grid item xs={4} ></Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4} ></Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4} ></Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4} ></Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4} ></Grid>
</Grid>
```

And I use this component in another component, which also has a series of grids..**component address**:

```
  <Grid container  spacing={10}>
        <Grid item>
          <form >
            <Region></Region>
            <Grid container spacing={10}> 
            <Grid item xs={4} ></Grid>
            </Grid>
          <form >
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

What I want is for this gride to be a continuation of the other grids, but for me it goes to the next line.
What should I do to get the grid inside the **address component** in the following **component region**?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to have all grid items in the same grid container. So:

1. remove the top container and item, because you only got one item and it doesn't make sense.
2. remove the container from **Region** component and use a **Fragment**
3. remove the container from **Address**

Region:

```
<>
    <Grid item xs={4}>1</Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>2</Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>3</Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>4</Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>5</Grid>
</>
```

Form:

```
<form>
    <Grid container spacing={10}>
        <Region />
        
        <Grid item xs={4} >6</Grid>
    </Grid>
</form>
```